# Concatenate large CSV files with columns out of order

Tags: python

I have thousands of CSV files (>100 GB in total) and would like to standardize them. It seems they have all the same separator and quote character. I am not 100% sure of that, but I will take this for granted. However, the CSVs have different headers. Some column names are the same, but the order can change from file to file. I want to match the columns with the same name and add the others to concatenate them in one single file, remove duplicates, and finally export them to SQLite or Parquet.

I have started using Dask (Python) to accomplish this; is it the best way to go in this case? What would be other modern approaches to this problem? Any suggestion on libraries to automate this process of checking and sanitizing lots of CSV files?

Comment: Instead of fiddling with the CSV files you could try to directly import them into a database. Considering the amount of data this will make more sense in the end. And I am not sure if SQLite is a good choice for such an amount of data.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense; the issue is that I need to clean them before importing in a database since the CSV files are not standardized (I've found three different encodings in the files) and the columns are out of order. It would be great to have a SQL smart enough to deal with different schemas and encoding alone...

Comment: A well designed data import tool would use the column name instead of it's index. May be looking at NoSQL databases would also make sense (e.g. MongoDB) as you can import the records/documents into the database without having to know all column names from all files.

Comment: Thanks, Robert, it is a good idea, indeed! I will take a look!